# insert if update subquery returns 0 rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Specs:

PostgreSQL 9.2.18 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit

I'm on MacOS 13.2.1, using DBeaver IDE (version 23.0.4.202305071722) to connect to the database.

---

I am trying to re-write what is essentially an upsert query. Since the database I'm using is on an older postgres version, I am unable to use the more recent upsert syntax of `ON CONFLICT DO ...`.

The table I am upserting against is setup to have an `id` column of type `serial4`, such that every row has a unique id number which is set by default. Additionally, there is a unique constraint on `col3` and `col4` so that there are no two rows with the same `col3` and `col4` values.

Here is an SQLFiddle showing an example version of this table and the current (working) upsert query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94a73/1

The query I currently have, which does work, uses `with subquery as (...)` syntax/structure. However, I would prefer to have the query not use that syntax, and instead have the subquery inside the `insert` query.

Here is the existing query:

```
with upsert as (
    update tbl
    set col1='123', col2='456'
    where id=(
        select id
        from tbl
        where col3='baz'
        and col4='bat'
    )
    returning *
)
insert into tbl (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select '123', '456', 'baz', 'bat'
where not exists (select * from upsert)
```

The result of this query is that if there is a row in the table where `col3='baz'` and `col4='bat'`, that row's values for `col1` and `col2` are updated to `123` and `456`, respectively. If there is no such row, a new row is inserted with those values.

---

The re-structured query I have right now is as follows:

```
insert into tbl (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bat'
where not exists (
    select * from (
        update tbl
        set col1='foo', col2='bar'
        where id=(
            select id from tbl
            where col3='baz'
            and col4='bat'
        )
        returning *
    ) upsert
)
```

When I try to run the query, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "set"
```

I tried changing the `select 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bat'` to `values ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bat')`, but that gives a different error message:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
```

I believe the issue is that I'm messing up my syntax somewhere, but I'm unable to discern where.

---

To reiterate my question -- is it possible to re-structure the working query I have so that it doesn't use the `with subquery as ...` syntax? If so, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That Postgres install is in dire need of an update. "Older" is putting it mildly.

Comment: You can't run an update as a subquery, only in a CTE. But before you spend any more time on version 9.2, do yourself a favor and upgrade to something slightly more modern. Version 9.2 is EOL since November 2017

Comment: @tadman I absolutely agree with you. Unfortunately, the real-world context surrounding this database is ALL horrendously out of date and I don't see that changing anytime soon.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks for the information on that. I do agree that my company needs to update the database, though I had no idea it was so out of date, wow. Unfortunately, this is what I'm stuck with and it is unlikely we will be able to upgrade it anytime soon.

Comment: I feel for you. This would be so much easier with a Postgres from this decade!

Answer (score 1):

As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204002/insert-if-update-subquery-returns-0-rows#comment134385205_76204002), Postgres does not support running an update as a subquery. As such, I do need to use it in a CTE, which is the `with subquery as (...)` syntax that I was referring to in my question. For future reference of anyone else who may be interested, I found helpful relevant information about CTEs (Common Table Expressions) [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Since I did not know the specific terminology (CTE) to describe the existing query I was working with, I was unable to find useful information to answer my question. The above-linked comment did resolve my question by providing that missing piece of knowledge and, as such, I will accept it as an answer should it be posted as such. Thanks again for the assistance!